# Loading format other than shapefile with ArcGIS runtime 100

Tags: sqlite, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf

I know how to load a feature table for ArcGIS runtime 100 in C#

```
ShapefileFeatureTable myShapefile = await 
ShapefileFeatureTable.OpenAsync(Path);
FeatureLayer fl= new FeatureLayer(myShapefile);
```

But how would I do this for another format like SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are many ways to load data from SQlite DB to Feature Table. Below is the method I used in one of my projects:

1. Create a class that properties contain all the required parameter
       for Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Data.Feature class. (attributes and geometry
       in this case)
2. Create a new sqlite connection using
           SQLiteConnection, avaliable from Microsoft.Data.Sqlite. Store features as records inside of the SQlite DB.
3. When generating FeatureTable, Create a new instance
   ArcGISFeatureTable, and load record stored in SQLite DB to create
   feature object. Use AddAsync(Feature) method in ArcGISFeatureTable
   class to add these features.

Just to be clear, this is method for ArcGISFeatureTable, not ShapefileFeatureTable